# using ffmpeg to convert a mkv or mp4 suitable for a DVD player that supports MPEG-4 / DivX

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I got a DVD Player with USB support. It is a recent player (DVD-225), but the documentation is sparse, but it does claim MPEG-4 and DivX support.

Now, I have got certain AVI files to play via USB, but everything else fails. I looked at the metadata of an AVI file that worked via ffprobe, and got the following:

```
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.101   Duration: 00:58:30.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1336 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (xvid / 0x64697678), yuv420p, 640x290 [SAR 1:1 DAR 64:29], 1196 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr,
23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

Now, I figured that if I can replicate the above, I can convert most things to play via USB, even if it isn't the most up to date codecs.

I've tried various combinations, but they all fail. The closest I got was by using the following shell script:

```
for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v mpeg4 -vtag divx -qscale:v 3 -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 "_${i%.*}.avi"; done
```

This has a strange result that it will play the audio track, but not the video track. The metadata I got from this was:

```
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:58:07.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3026 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (divx / 0x78766964), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 3:4 DAR 4:3], 2901 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 24k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : ******************
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 109 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : ******************
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong with this ? I've converted AVI, MKV and MP4 files, and while they work on my computer, the DVD player seems to be very picky.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks
Neil

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like 1280x720. Try `ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v mpeg4 -vf scale="640:-2" -vtag divx -qscale:v 3 -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 -t 60 output.avi`. Or try `-c:v libxvid` instead of `-c:v mpeg4` (if your ffmpeg has `--enable-libxvid`).

Answer (score 0):

@llogan - Hi, just tried this out, and it seems that your answer was largely correct. I had to use "-vtag DIVX" with divx in capital letters. God knows why.

Anyway, thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `.mpg` format. I have tested this on 7+ years old DVD player.

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -target pal-dvd -q:v 10 output.mpg
```

`-q:v` controls the quality of the output (1-31). Lower the number, higher the quality but larger file size.